# Lists of data types: "could not deduce (a ~ SomeType) from the context (SomeTypeclass a)"

Tags: haskell, types

I have the following problem with Haskell's type system: I am trying to declare a data type and return a list containing elements of this type from a function. Unfortunately, even a minimal testcase such as

```
data SampleType = SampleTypeConstructor

instance Show SampleType where
    show x = "(SampleType)"

stList :: (Show a) => [a]
stList = [(SampleTypeConstructor)]

main = do {
    putStrLn (show stList)
}
```

fails with the following error message from both ghc-7.0.2 and ghc-7.1.20110327:

```
tcase.hs:7:12:
    Could not deduce (a ~ SampleType)
    from the context (Show a)
      bound by the type signature for stList :: Show a => [a]
      at tcase.hs:7:1-34
      `a' is a rigid type variable bound by
          the type signature for stList :: Show a => [a] at tcase.hs:7:1
    In the expression: (SampleTypeConstructor)
    In the expression: [(SampleTypeConstructor)]
    In an equation for `stList': stList = [(SampleTypeConstructor)]
```

Answer (score 21, accepted):

the offending line is `stList :: (Show a) => [a]`. You're declaring that stList is a polymorphic list that holds any element which satisfies the show constraint. But stList isn't a polymorphic list! It's a list of `SampleType`s. So remove the signature and see what ghci infers, or just give it the correct signature: `:: [SampleType]`.

Answer (score 21):

```
stList :: (Show a) => [a]
```

is saying that given *any* `Show` instance for *any* type `a`, you are going return a list of elements of that type.

```
stList = [SampleTypeConstructor]
```

is returning list of `SampleType`s, while that is a list of elements for which there exists a `Show` instance, it is not a list that works for every choice of `a`.

In reality the only inhabitant you are likely to find for this type that doesn't involve bottoms is `[]`, because `Show a` doesn't provide any mechanism to construct an `a`.

To fix this you can do one of a few things, depending on your end goal.

You may just want to let `stList` have the more narrow type:

```
stList :: [SampleType]
```

You may want to build some kind of type like

```
newtype Showable = Showable (Int -> String -> String)
```

which explicitly captures the relevant portion of the Show instance. (You can also do this with an existential type, but this version is Haskell 98.)

```
instance Show Showable where
    showsPrec d (Showable f) = f d

showable :: Show a => a -> Showable
showable a = Showable (\d -> showsPrec d a)
```

Then you could make a list of Showables.

```
stList :: [Showable]
stList = [showable SampleTypeConstructor]
```

But ultimately it depends on what you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: Well, I wanted to accomplish some polymorphism (list contains elements of whatever which all abide by a typeclass), but only after a few hours of sleep did I realize that the default lists provided by Haskell aren't polymorphic. Whoops, sorry.

Answer (score 1):

Haskell does support heterogenous lists of elements, provided their elements are correctly wrapped (see live code on [repl.it](https://repl.it/@pierrecarbonnelle/Showable)):

```
{-# LANGUAGE GADTs #-}

-- your sample type
data SampleType = SampleConstructor

instance Show SampleType where
  show _ = "(SampleType)"

-- MkShowable wrapper
data Showable where
  MkShowable :: Show a => a -> Showable

instance Show Showable where
  show (MkShowable a) = show a


main = do
  let myList :: [Showable]
      myList = [MkShowable SampleConstructor, MkShowable 1, MkShowable True]
  putStrLn $ show myList
  -- ["(SampleType)","1","True"]
```

See [Heterogenous collections](https://wiki.haskell.org/Heterogenous_collections) for more options.