# Haskell Could not deduce ... from the Context error

Tags: haskell

I have type classes, for all of which I would like to have some common behavior. My problem is explained in the following code:

```
class A a
class B b

class X x where
    method :: (A a, B b) =>  x -> a -> b

data T = L | M | N
data U = P | Q | R

instance A T
instance B U

data Y = ZZZ

instance X Y where
    method _ L = P
    method _ M = Q
    method _ N = R
```

When I load this module, I get the following error:

```
example.hs:19:14:
    Could not deduce (a ~ T)
    from the context (A a, B b)
      bound by the type signature for method :: (A a, B b) => Y -> a -> b
      at example.hs:(17,5)-(19,18)
      `a' is a rigid type variable bound by
          the type signature for method :: (A a, B b) => Y -> a -> b
          at example.hs:17:5
    In the pattern: N
    In an equation for `method': method _ N = R
    In the instance declaration for `X Y'

example.hs:19:18:
    Could not deduce (b ~ U)
    from the context (A a, B b)
      bound by the type signature for method :: (A a, B b) => Y -> a -> b
      at example.hs:(17,5)-(19,18)
      `b' is a rigid type variable bound by
          the type signature for method :: (A a, B b) => Y -> a -> b
          at example.hs:17:5
    In the expression: R
    In an equation for `method': method _ N = R
    In the instance declaration for `X Y'
Failed, modules loaded: none.
```

I am at loss what to do in this case. Even when T and U are instance of A and B, I get this error. If I cannot return a rigid type value from `method`, how do I code this part?

Comment: possible duplicate of [lists of data types: "could not deduce (a ~ SomeType) from the context (SomeTypeclass a)"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5453514/lists-of-data-types-could-not-deduce-a-sometype-from-the-context-sometype)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The signature `method :: (A a, B b) =>  x -> a -> b` promises that `method` works for **every** pair of types `(a, b)` with `a` an instance of `A` and `b` an instance of `B`, but you define it to work only with two specific types.

This is fundamentally different from interfaces in Java or the like, where the callee chooses which type is used, the only thing the caller knows is that interface X is implemented. In Haskell, given such a signature, the caller decides which types are used (here, what type is passed as second argument and what type shall be returned) and the callee has to be able to provide the demanded functionality (as long as the demanded types are instances of the required classes).

Without any methods in classes `A` and `B` to analyse respectively construct values of an instance of that class, you cannot implement `method` other than with `undefined` (various degrees of undefinedness are possible due to `seq`), so you would have to tell the world that you are in fact using `T` and `U`.

Another way is to make `X` a multiparameter type class,

```
{-# LANGUAGE MultiParamTypeClasses #-}

class (A a, B b) => X x a b where
    method :: x -> a -> b
```

However, that might require functional dependencies to resolve instances. Another way would be to use associated types,

```
{-# LANGUAGE TypeFamilies #-}

class X x where
    type AType x
    type BType x
    method :: x -> AType x -> BType x

instance X Y where
    type AType Y = T
    type BType Y = U
    method ...
```

Comment: I got your point. I have the type classes Y,T,U working together. I have another triplet of type classes Y1, T1, U1 that work together. In my problem, these type-classes form instances of a model. I would like to have a common code that work on these models without caring about how they are implemented. Thanks though for the pointing the problem. This kind of code would be a problem in java like languages too.

Comment: MultiParamTypeClasses along with functional dependencies resolved my problem. Good. :)

Answer (score 3):

It's really hard to think about a way to rescue your example (for the reasons mentioned by Daniel Fischer). If you have two totally unrelated type classes A and B, how should you establish a general connection? So you could put both together, but I doubt that this is what you want:

```
{-# LANGUAGE MultiParamTypeClasses #-}

class A2B a b where
  convert :: a -> b

data T = L | M | N
data U = P | Q | R

instance A2B T U where
  convert L = P
  convert M = Q
  convert N = R  

data Y = ZZZ

class X x where
    method :: (A2B a b) =>  x -> a -> b

instance X Y where
    method _ t = convert t
```

And this design isn't very stable either: You'll get in trouble when you want to have instances like `A2B T V` next to `A2B T U`.