# Haskell : How to cast a data type to one of its specific typeclass?

Tags: haskell

I want to cast MySqlFakeClient and MySqlHttpClient to their common typeclass MySqlClient and I have this issue :

[image]

for the following code :

```
loadClient :: MySqlClient client => String -> client
loadClient "fake" =  MySqlFakeClient 1 -- <- It's complaining here...
loadClient "prod" =  MySqlHttpClient "http://www.google.com"
loadClient _ = error "unknown"

data MySqlHttpClient = MySqlHttpClient String
data MySqlFakeClient = MySqlFakeClient Int

class MySqlClient client where
    config :: client -> String

instance MySqlClient MySqlHttpClient where

  config (MySqlHttpClient url) = url

instance MySqlClient MySqlFakeClient where

  config (MySqlFakeClient myInt) = show myInt
```

can't we do it in Haskell ?

Comment: You probably just want `data SqlClient = Http String | Fake Int; loadClient :: String -> SqlClient` (and no typeclass at all).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This page : https://wiki.haskell.org/Existential_type , answered my question (basically using existential types, like @Rampion suggested ...):

```
class Shape_ a where
   perimeter :: a -> Double
   area      :: a -> Double

 data Shape = forall a. Shape_ a => Shape a

 type Radius = Double
 type Side   = Double

 data Circle    = Circle    Radius
 data Rectangle = Rectangle Side Side
 data Square    = Square    Side


 instance Shape_ Circle where
   perimeter (Circle r) = 2 * pi * r
   area      (Circle r) = pi * r * r

 instance Shape_ Rectangle where
   perimeter (Rectangle x y) = 2*(x + y)
   area      (Rectangle x y) = x * y

 instance Shape_ Square where
   perimeter (Square s) = 4*s
   area      (Square s) = s*s

 instance Shape_ Shape where
   perimeter (Shape shape) = perimeter shape
   area      (Shape shape) = area      shape


 --
 -- Smart constructor
 --

 circle :: Radius -> Shape
 circle r = Shape (Circle r)

 rectangle :: Side -> Side -> Shape
 rectangle x y = Shape (Rectangle x y)

 square :: Side -> Shape
 square s = Shape (Square s)

 shapes :: [Shape]
 shapes = [circle 2.4, rectangle 3.1 4.4, square 2.1]
```

Answer (score 9):

This is not how Haskell works. A type signature like

```
loadClient :: MySqlClient client => String -> client
```

does *not* mean that `client` may be any type that has an instance for `MySqlClient`. It means (roughly) the *caller* gets to choose a type that has an instance `MySqlClient` and `loadClient` will return whatever the caller has chosen. This type is fixed at compile time, whereas you probably want something dynamic.

The way around this is, for this example, rather simple: If all you want is a `String`, just return that instead:

```
loadClient "fake" = show 1
loadClient "prod" = "http://www.google.com"
```

Now you might think "my use case is more complicated than this, this will not work for me" - but you can easily extend this to more complicated cases. Basically, anything you would otherwise write in your `class` you can just put into a `data` instead (if you're not using things like `TypeFamilies` obviously, but that wouldn't make sense for dynamic things like these anyway).

Consider for example:

```
data WriteBackend = WriteBackend { write :: String -> IO (), close :: IO () } 

getBackend :: String -> IO WriteBackend
getBackend ":null:" = return (WriteBackend (const $ return ()) (return()))
getBackend ":console:" = return $ WriteBackend putStrLn (return())
getBackend filename = do
  h <- openFile filename WriteMode
  return $ WriteBackend (hPutStrLn h) (hClose h)
```

Which you could use like this:

```
greetBackend :: WriteBackend -> IO ()
greetBackend b = write b "Hello World!"

main = do
  nullBackend <- getBackend ":null:"
  consoleBackend <- getBackend ":console:"
  fileBackend <- getBackend "file.txt"
  greetBackend nullBackend -- does nothing
  greetBackend consoleBackend -- writes to console
  greetBackend fileBackend -- writes to file
  close nullBackend -- does nothing
  close consoleBackend -- does nothing
  close fileBackend -- closes file
```

Note that this is just if you genuinely need a dynamic approach - i.e. you don't know or care what the actual implementation is as long as it provides the right interface. If you have a limited number of cases you actually want to distinguish between, you should just use a sum type as @Daniel Wagner suggested.

Answer (score 5):

Another solution is to use existential types:

```
loadClient :: String -> SomeMySqlClient
loadClient "fake" =  SomeMySqlClient $ MySqlFakeClient 1
loadClient "prod" =  SomeMySqlClient $ MySqlHttpClient "http://www.google.com"
loadClient _ = error

data SomeMySqlClient = forall t. MySqlClient t => SomeMySqlClient t
instance MySqlClient SomeMySqlClient where
  config (SomeMySqlClient t) = config t
```

Comment: This is the direct equivalent of the hypothetical OOP version—an existentially quantified value with a typeclass constraint is basically an object with a vtable—but also in Haskell it’s usually overkill if you’re only packing one value.

Comment: @JonPurdy agreed on the overkill note.

Answer (score 1):

Typeclasses aren't types, or superclasses in OO nomenclature; they're more like templates in C++, creating variants of similarly named functions based on types. The class is saying that both `MySqlHttpClient` and `MySqlFakeClient` have instances of the `config` function, but any given value still has a concrete type. The compiler expects to be able to resolve the concrete types at compile time during type analysis, but the argument distinction between your two patterns is only in the value, not type. Being two patterns of the same function (not instances of distinct typeclasses), their types must match, and that fails. Also, I assume you meant `error "unknown"` or `undefined` in the default pattern.

[Lists of data types: "could not deduce (a ~ SomeType) from the context (SomeTypeclass a)"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5453514/lists-of-data-types-could-not-deduce-a-sometype-from-the-context-sometype) shows the same issue.

So I can write a `loadClient` function of the given type assuming I *don't* know, in that function, which concrete MySqlClient it creates:

```
loadClient :: MySqlClient client => String -> client
loadClient a = case a of
    "fake" -> create "1"
    -- "prod" -> create "http://www.google.com" :: MySqlHttpClient
    _ -> undefined

data MySqlHttpClient = MySqlHttpClient String
data MySqlFakeClient = MySqlFakeClient Int

class MySqlClient client where
    config :: client -> String
    create :: String -> client

instance MySqlClient MySqlHttpClient where
    config (MySqlHttpClient url) = url
    create url = MySqlHttpClient url

instance MySqlClient MySqlFakeClient where
    config (MySqlFakeClient myInt) = show myInt
    create num = MySqlFakeClient (read num)
```

But this doesn't solve your dilemma, as this also implied I couldn't discriminate between the `create` functions and only one of them will be possible when the type becomes concrete.